# Is there a way to suppress a specific hook in tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, hook

I would like to suppress a single hook in tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession, whilst running the others. Is there a way to do this? Currently, I run into errors when a hook runs an operation on a `sess.run()` that it shouldn't run on. An example of the operator I'm looking for is:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
   hooks=[hook1, hook2, hook3, hook4]
) as sess:
   sess.run_partial_hook(fetches=[...], suppress=[hook2, hook3], feed_dict={...})
```

To add some info, I know that there is a `sess.run_step_fn` that runs the session without added hooks. I've also considered the possibility of manually writing the hooks such that they skip the `sess.run()` when wanted.

Comment: The functionality does not exist as such, but why are the two possibilities that you mention (`run_step_fn` and using custom deactivatable hooks) not good for you?

Comment: Well, it would surely get the job done, but to the cost of much more code for writing custom hooks. It would be easier to have an operator where you can decide which hooks will run or not!